# SQL Subquery within a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a nested SQL where I need to have a subquery within a subquery

Let's say I am trying to retrieve a row from ORDERS that matches MAIN_ID from SOURCE that matches MODULE from MODULES.

```
Select MAIN_ID from ORDERS
where MAIN_ID in (select MAIN_ID
                  from SOURCE
                  where MODULE in (select MODULE
                                   from MODULES
                                   where MODULE2 = 'zzzz'))
```

This results in a bunch of rows returning 0's. Not sure how I can get around it. Only thing I know is MODULE2 in this case which is 'zzzz'. I have to be able to reverse back to find the row from ORDERS table.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Which DBMS you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: This looks like a simple inner join of the tables?

Comment: @NicholasHunter - using SQL server

Comment: @jarlh - this is part of a bigger query so it is tough to get to the expected result right now. But if I can return MAIN_ID as part of this query, it would do the job

Comment: @Stu - May be but I was not able to get to proper results that way so I went this route

Comment: Your query will _retrieve rows from ORDERS that matches MAIN_ID from SOURCE that matches MODULE from MODULES where MODULE2 is equal to 'zzzz'_.

Comment: Right, that is acceptable output. Currently it is returning 0s

Comment: We can't see your data. Post sample data to illustrate your issue!

Comment: *"This results in a bunch of rows returning 0's."* because you have multiple rows in the table `ORDERS` where the value of `MAIN_ID` is `0`, *and* that `MAIN_ID` appears in the table `SOURCE` where the `MODULE` column (in the table `SOURCE`) appears in the table `MODULES` when the column `MODULE2` (in the table `MODULES`) has the value `'zzzz'`.

Comment: **Without sample data we are all guessing in the dark** and I guess you are not giving us your full query either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to write the query as a join. Maybe you can see why zeros are returned

```
Select O.*, S.*, M.* 
from ORDERS O 
JOIN SOURCE S ON S.MAIN_ID = O.MAIN_ID
JOIN MODULES M ON S.MODULE = M.MODULE
WHERE M.MODULE2 = 'zzzz'
```

Comment: Why `*` against all the tables?

Comment: He said that he gets "a bunch of rows returning 0's". So selecting * might help him to see why the rows are returned. Maybe these are special/old/test records. With a join and selecting all columns he at least sees all relevant information.